# Can't apply language

Tags: 17.04, input-language

In ubuntu I can't apply any language system wide. Though I have installed language pack
[image]
As you can see those language are not selectable . I am using ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 6):

You must **drag and drop** the languages in the list into the preference order you desire. Applications will then use the topmost language in the list which they do support.

Note that the `English` element is the default language supported by every package. Therefore all languages in the list below this element are disabled and ignored.

So what you have to do is to either drag your Hindi (or whatever that language is, I don't know) language elements up, or the `English` one down.

As *@Gunnar Hjalmarsson* pointed out in his comments, it is not allowed to put any non-English languages between your highest enabled country-specific English language element and the default `English` element, because that would make few sense. See the comments for his more detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm guilty of any restrictions as regards the order of the items. Please give me details on something you failed to set, and I'll try to explain the rationale for it.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Okay, it probably isn't a really useful one anyway, but one "impossible order" I can quickly come up with as example when having German and English language packs installed is [English UK - English US - German Germany - English - (other stuff...)]

Comment: That's correct. Reason: Since you prefer an English option, and English is always available, having German as a fallback language would be a no-op. If you click the "Help" button from the Language Support GUI, you open a document which tries to explain the thinking behind the "language priority list".

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson So I can't put any non-English language in between any language from the "English (country)" type and plain fallback "English"? Are that all restrictions?

Comment: Basically. And in 17.04: If you put "English (US)" at the top, you can't add anything else before the "English" item (since English US is the original language and always available anyway).

Comment: Aha, thank you for the explanations. I learned something today :)

Comment: If you start the thing from terminal (via `gnome-language-selector`) a warning message appears if you try to set something it doesn't accept. Ideally it should be a graphical message, but the fact that we now move to GNOME as default makes it less likely that such an improvement will happen.